# Jquery,AJAX & PHP, form submition not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

Basically i am trying to create a validation for the form. I want it to check if it can connect to the DB and if true to proceed to another page and if false to return an error.

I am inputting the wrong details to make it just display the error but somehow it always returns "TRUE" on page load... and everytime i click the submit it doesnt do anything regardless of my entry...

thx

```
       <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
    var u = $('#username');
    var s = $('#server');
    var p = $('#password');

    $('#iValForm').submit(
    $.post("connect.php", {u: u.val(),p: p.val(),s: s.val()}, function(fd){
        if (fd == "true"){
        alert("Is: " + fd);
        return false;
                        } // if1
        if (fd == "false"){
        alert("Is2: " + fd);
        return false;
                        } // if2
    } //post function

    ) //Post    
    ) //submit
  }) //document

      </script>

    <form class="iValForm" id="iValForm" method="post">
    <fieldset>
    <legend id="error"> </legend>
    <p>
        <label for="username">Username </label>
        <input id="username" name="username" class="required" /> </input>
    </p>
    <p> 
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input id="password" name="password" class="required"/> </input>
    </p>

    <p> 
        <label for="server">Server</label>
        <input id="server" name="server" class="required"/> </input>

    </p>
    <p>
         <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </p>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Connect.php

```
<?php
$user = $_POST['u'];
$password = $_POST['p'];
$server = $_POST['s'];

@$con = mysql_connect ($server, $user, $password);


if (!$con) { 
    $response = "false";
    echo $response;


    } else { 
        $response = "true";
        echo $response;
    }

?>
```

Comment: I know it's a "bit" late but are you still having this problem? You might try outputting the variable `$con` through `print_r()` so you can see what it's actually outputting...

Answer (score 1):

change your php script

```
if (!$con) { 
    $response = 'false';
    echo $response;


    } else { 
        $response = 'true';
        echo $response;
    }
```

and in javascript

```
if (data == 'false')
```

Comment: Just did, still not showing the alert or the error in the page

Comment: Can you check with your firebug what response you are getting from the server?

Comment: I just put firebug and didnt get anything :S

Comment: Did you see the request being made properly in firebug? Can you confirm you are correctly passing the parameters to php script via ajax call?

Comment: The weird thing is that if i change to .keyup the php works and returns what it should, so then the problem is on my jQuery. but somehow it does not even show in firebug an error as it is right now

Comment: I can not see the request being passed via AJAX in firebug :S.... But they are passing if i try on keyup instead of onsubmit `$(document).ready(function () {
 var u = $('#username');
 var s = $('#server');
 var p = $('#password');
 
 $('#server').keyup(function () {
   $.post("connect.php", { s: s.val(), u: u.val() , p: p.val() },
    function(data) {
    $('#error').html('checking availability...' + u.val() + " " + p.val() + " " + s.val() + data);
     
    
        }
     ); 
   });
 
});`

Comment: try changing <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/> to <input class="submit" id ='submit' type="button" value="Submit"/> and $('#iValForm').submit(function() { to $('#submit').click(function() {

Comment: Ok, i redesigned it a bit and now the error is different, it just always return true on pageload instead on clicking the submit button